# jquery mobile - How to manual markup html?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I using ajax to load a page and insert it into a div on the current page. How to mark it up? I don't use $.mobile.changePage, and I just want to know how to manual mark up by using javascript. Don't ask why please.

Comment: I won't ask why, but what? Can you give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: First I using ajax to load a html file with jquery mobile list view in it. Next, using $('#container').html(ajax_result). But the list view does not mark up yet.

Answer (score 0):

W/out actually knowing what you are doing, if you add any markup to an item you will need to call the "refresh" event.

eg: `$("#selectbox").html(optionList).selectmenu('refresh', true);`

Markup is added to an element in the normal jQuery way.  Given that's not in the question I won't go through that.

You could use FireBug in FireFox to look at the elements and write out the new ones in the exact same manner with all the classes but that is kinda dangerous.